# Mootools snow fall script, trying to make it smoother

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to create a snow falling, and I have it working. But it is not smooth at all. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it then Fx.Morph. I have a timer running every 50 milliseconds, but my snowflakes don't seem to move until the Fx.Morph is finished, so sometimes they sit there and wait.

Source is at http://jsfiddle.net/yQCza/4/

```
move = new Fx.Morph(ele, {
    transition: randomTransition,
    duration: randomDuration
  });
```

Any ideas as to what I could do to make it smoother?

Comment: Just a guess, but the easeInOut in your transitions might be causing the jerky motion.

Comment: It's not so much jerky as if you see http://jsfiddle.net/yQCza/4/embedded/result/ you'll see the snowflakes stop, hang there, then move again.

Comment: Actually if I change it to linear it fixes it... HRMMMMMMMM

Comment: have a look at an old script I co-wrote 3-4 yrs ago, just fixed it to work for mootools 1.4.5 :) http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/xug2d/

Comment: THanks Dimitar, that will give me an idea of what to do. Rather then doing the transitions I found it to be smoother to just flat out change the css top and left properties every 40 milliseconds.

Comment: Don't forget to use request animation frame instead of setInterval/setTimer. http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/